# Rails: Chartkick gem - Sum up the Revenue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Chartkick gem. This code snipped should actually show the revenue made by a specific user:

```
<%= area_chart Order.where(:user_name => current_user.name).group_by_day(:created_at).maximum(:totalprice), library: {isStacked: false, vAxis: {title: "Revenue"}, hAxis: {title: 'Date'}} %>
```

But it only shows the last entry of `totalprice`. So for example, if there are 2 articles sold on a specific day (e.g. 300 + 600 USD worth) it only shows the 600 USD mark. How can I transform the code above so it sums up all `Order.totalprice` entries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing `maximum`

Comment: Doesn't work. `.maximum` should be there regarding http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum gets the highest total price, you want sum if you want to add them together.

```
<%= area_chart Order.where(:user_name => current_user.name).group_by_day(:created_at).sum(:totalprice), library: {isStacked: false, vAxis: {title: "Revenue"}, hAxis: {title: 'Date'}} %>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("orders"."totalprice") AS sum_totalprice, (DATE_T...`

Comment: What is the type on the `totalprice` column?

Comment: `t.string   "totalprice"`I needed it as a string, as I`m handling "," as well as "." as separators.

Comment: It need to be a `smallint, int, bigint, real, double precision, numeric, interval, or money` type.  Switch it to that because it makes no sense to have a price stored as a string, and you can use `number_to_currency` helper to format it in your views.

Comment: That does actually not work, as I'm working with German, UK and USA currencies. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Why not?  You can pass the unit, seperator and delimiter with number to currency.